# Complex Node-Coordinate hirearchy collision detection

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I'm having a problem getting two "hitboxes" to be in the same plane or some such. I know the answer lies somewhere in the convertToNodeSpace or the convertToWorldSpace methods, but despite looking at the API and some examples and trying things out I'm still not sure how to best change my Node/Worldspace to get the correct comparisson

My Hirearchy is as follows. I want to compare the two boundingBox quantities

```
SCENE
   -GameLayer
      -HeroCharacter
         -Sprite
            -boundingBox
      -WorldLayer
         -EnemyCharacter
            -EnemySprite
               -boundingBox
```

It strikes me that it might be much simplet to have the WorldLayer be a child of the SCENE, I will try that- but I would still like to know how to compare the two quantities

**EDIT:** Turns out it was much easier to make GameLayer and WorldLayer on the same level. My collision works as expected now- however I would still like to know how to make the other version work just for my own eddification

**EDITEDIT:**
I now have come to the conclusion that I really do need to understand how this works, because I am finding competing information and getting really complex parent-child collision  and placement issues. Any resources are awesome. The API hasn't really helped me out much

Comment: I would convert both bounding boxes to world space and then check for collision

Comment: I have a method that computes both hitboxes into worldspace, basically it's like [self hitbox] returns CGRectMake rect with worldspace converted sprite location. It works when both sprites are at the same "depth" but not otherwise